# How to implement MVVM for Xamarin.form ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working on an app that has a main page called `ItemsPage` contains a `ListView` and another page called `DetailPage`, I'm trying to move the `OnItemSelected` function from `ItemsPage` class to `ItemsPageModel`. The function I'm trying to implement is once the item is clicked, another `DetailPage` should pop up with the details of the clicked item. What should I do? thanks!

```
ItemsPage:  public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage {
        ItemsViewModel viewModel;

        public ItemsPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args) {
            var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
            if (item == null)
                return;
            var viewModel = BindingContext as ItemsViewModel;
            viewModel.SelectedItem = item;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));
            // Manually deselect item.
            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
}
```

```
 <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 HasUnevenRows="true"
                 RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                 IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                 IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                 CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                 ItemSelected ="OnItemSelected"
                  >
```

Comment: You can use behaviour to bind your selection event with a command in the view model.  You can look into this on how to implement a reusable event command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior

Comment: When you navigate to DetailPage ,  you can pass the data to this page. And you have already done this , then what's the special problem?